# Does the function level influence the region of memory allocation of a variable from main

Tags: c, function, pointers, memory

I want to create a function that allocates space for a pointer (from main) to point at. If having the memory allocated in a function, will this memory still be available and safe to use after the that function returns? Here is an example of code:

```
int foo(int **number)
{
    *number = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
}

int main()
{
    int *myVar;
    foo(&myVar);
}
```

So we see that the memory is allocated in the process of execution of the `foo()` function.

Will the memory for the `myVar` variable be allocated in "space" of the `foo()` function, or in "space" of the `main()`?

After finishing the execution of the `foo()`, its memory is being cleared. Will `myVar` point to the same "space"? Will it be safe to use?

Could it be overwritten by other function, or variable declarations?

Comment: "*that allocates space for a pointer*" well, your code allocates space for an `int`, not *for* pointer. Still, it assigns the address of the memory allocated (for an `int`)  *to* a pointer. Accurate wording is essential in this context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the memory will not be cleared or deallocated at the end of `foo`. And yes, your pointer `myVar` in `main` will correctly point to the memory you allocated in `foo`. (You don't need the explicit cast to `int *`, BTW).

The whole purpose of dynamic memory is to defeat all lifetime rules imposed by "scopes", "functions" and such. The memory allocated by `malloc` exists independently of any functions and their "spaces". This memory will persist until you yourself manually deallocate it. Dynamic memory (aka freestore, aka heap) persists as long as your program runs.

Note also that you are not allocating "space for a pointer". You are allocating a nameless memory block your pointer will point to. This block exist independently of any pointers. You can have a hundred pointers pointing to the same block, or you can have none at all.

Comment: Thank you very much. Short and to the point. Helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

What's specific to a function is a local variable which can be a pointer itself. These variables exist on the stack and are cleaned up with the scope of the function ie - when the function exits.

But when memory is allocated using `malloc`/`calloc`, the area alloted is in the heap which is agnostic to the lifetime of functions. A pointer to this memory area is returned which is a variable in scope of some function or maybe `main` itself. In your case - `int *myVar`.

Hence as long as your process runs the pointer obtained(using `malloc`/`calloc`) anywhere would be valid(unless you free it deliberately).

To ensure you have the memory area accessible, you need to use [pass by reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373419/whats-the-difference-between-passing-by-reference-vs-passing-by-value) or return the pointer itself.

Comment: "*you need to use pass by reference*" C is always only and ever doing "*pass by value*". It does not know pass by reference (as opposed to C++).